# Converting selected null values from Panda dataframe from series to string

Tags: python, pandas

I have some null values in my dataframe that I created using pandas that appear like this when I print them:

```
0    NaN
5    NaN
9    NaN
```

How can I convert these values into a string once I grab them using Python and create an if expression like this:

```
if that_value == "NaN":
    do_something
```

Comment: Are these float `NaN` or the string `'NaN'` here? if it's real `NaN` then you must use `isnull()` e.g. `pd.isnull(df[col])` or `df[col].isnull()`

Comment: The dataframe is created out of an Excel table. Columns consist of float values (e.g. 0.23678) and empty cells. Those empty cells is what I see as NaN in the dataframe. There are quite a few columns like that in the dataframe. Are you suggesting I use `df[col].isnull()` for every columns like that?

Comment: what does `df.info()` show then, does it show `float64` or `object`?

Comment: When I print it, it shows up like this `0   NaN
Name: DeliveryPickup_Client, dtype: float64`

Comment: You can do `df['DeliveryPickup_Client'].fillna(some_value, inplace=True)` or if you just want to work on those rows: `df.loc[df['DeliveryPickup_Client'],isnull()]`

Comment: If I do it like this `if df.loc[df['DeliveryPickup_Client'].isnull()]: do_something` I get this error "if df.loc[df['DeliveryPickup_Client'].isnull()]:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 917, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I replaced all NaNs with zeros in my dataframe:

```
df.fillna("0", inplace=True)
```